# Why changing xib's constraint is invalid in url request's success block?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have written an ViewController using Interface Building: the top part is TableView, the bottom part is UIView(called bottomView).the tableView's bottom is the bottomView's top, and I add a height Constraint in the bottomView to control the height of the tableView.Then I link the bottomView's height constraint to my viewController's property. Let's see the xib picture about the ViewController.
[image: ViewController's xib]

the constraints in the viewController is in the picture followed(the first picture is tableView's, the second is the bottomBackView's):

[image]
　[image]
In the ViewController, I use IBOutlet corresponding the link like this:
`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomViewHeightConstraint;`
Now I change bottomViewHeightConstraint's constant in the url request's success block like this:

```
[getContacts startWithParams:@{@"bizId":self.bizId, @"bizCode":@(self.bizCode)} success:^(id responseObject) {
self.bottomViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.bottomContentView.height;
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

first time, the value of self.bottomViewHeightConstraint.constant is 70 here, and the result is right. the second time the value is 0, the expected result is like this(table view can scrolled to the screen bottom):[image]
But the actually result like this(the tableView can't scrolled to the screen bottom):[image]

According to the comment,I used GCD like this:

```
        dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{
        self.bottomContentView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, SCREENWIDTH, 0.0f);
        [self.bottomContentView configViewWithModel:model];
        self.bottomViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.bottomContentView.height;
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    });
```

It doesn't work too. There is one point troubled me too:when I change this constraint's constant in a method which is invoked in method 'viewDidLoad', it doesn't work if I don't call the method 'layoutIfNeeded' like this code(I think call method 'setNeedsLayout' is enough):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addBottomView];
}
- (void)addBottomView {
    self.bottomContentView.delegate = self;
    self.bottomContentView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, SCREENWIDTH, 0.0f);
    self.bottomViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.bottomBackView addSubview:self.bottomContentView];
}
```

Comment: maybe you can try put this code in main_queue

Comment: Exactly. All UI updates should be performed on the main thread, as per Apple's recommendation. Typically, these completion handlers for backgrounds tasks get executed on the background thread that completed the task. Use gcd to call your UI code on the main queue.

Comment: @NicolasMiari, I edited my question, please give some advices if possible, Thank you very much.

Comment: Other than switching to using `dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{...` (which is what I meant), I really don't know what can be happening...

Comment: you have to post all of your constraints and screenshots, only a height constraint can't help. Have you set bottomBackView's bottom space constraint? It seems you have

Comment: @Wingzero, Yes, I set the bottomBackView's bottom and the superView's bottom the same. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @huixing sorry I missd some info. try self.bottomViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0 directly, and call layoutIfNeeded, beucase we don't know what happens in [self.bottomContentView configViewWithModel:model];

Comment: @Wingzero, thank you for your enthusiastic. But I think it doesn't work too because I have tried. Maybe somewhere produced this problem, I will continue to check.

Comment: What I would suggest is add break points at viewWillLayoutSubViews and viewDidLayoutSubviews to debug, and figure out after calling layoutIfNeeded, the constraint value is correct.

Comment: @Wingzero, Thank you ,I will try.

Comment: @Wingzero, I have found the reason, there are some constraints produced by system because autoSizeSubView property, it produced some conflict.Thank you for your suggest.

Comment: you may want to self answer your findings.

Comment: oh, you mean I should answer my question myself?